# Array sizes being added instead of staying constant

Tags: python, arrays, list

I wish to add the contents of multiple arrays together in a single array, so I go over different files store the data in  an array and then add them, however the data seems to be getting appended rather than just being added. For example I want, a=[1,2,3,4], b=[2,3,4,5],c=[3,4,1,2] and the final array to be sum=[6,9,8,11]. but for some reason I am not able to perform this operation! I know its a stupid mistake somewhere!

```
x=[]
s=[]
S=[]
p=[]
P=[]
d=[]
D=[]
#print 'startS0 is %f' % S[0]     
#print 'startS1 is %f' % S[1]     

N=3
for i in xrange(1,N+1,1):
        stri = str(i)
        dos_file =open("DOS"+stri,"r")
        #dos_file =open("DOS1","r")
        print 'filename is %s' % dos_file
        for line_aa in dos_file.readlines():
                line_aa=line_aa.split()
                #x=[0]*1000
                #p=[0]*1000
                x.append(line_aa[0])
                s.append(line_aa[1])
                #p.append(line_aa[2])
                #d.append(line_aa[3])
        #dos_file.close()   
        x=[float(i) for i in x]
        s=[float(i) for i in s]
        print 's0 is %f' % s[998]
        print 's1 is %f' % s[999]
        sizes=len(s)
        print 'sizes is %d' % sizes
        S=[0]*sizes
        print 'S0 is %f' % S[0]
        print 'S1 is %f' % S[1]
        sizeS=len(s)
        print 'sizeS is %d' % sizeS
        #dos_file.close()   
        S_tot=[a + b for a, b in zip(s, S)]
        print 'S_tot0 is %f' % S_tot[0]
        print 'S_tot1 is %f' % S_tot[1]
        sizeS_tot=len(s)
        print 'sizeS_tot is %d' % sizeS_tot
        dos_file.close()
        #x=[0]*sizes
        #p=[0]*sizes

print 'endS0 is %f' % S_tot[0]
print 'endS1 is %f' % S_tot[1]
```

The result I get is:

```
filename is <open file 'DOS1', mode 'r' at 0x2aaaabe06540>

sizes is 1000

sizeS is 1000

sizeS_tot is 1000
filename is <open file 'DOS2', mode 'r' at 0x2aaaabe065d0>

sizes is 2000

sizeS is 2000

sizeS_tot is 2000
filename is <open file 'DOS3', mode 'r' at 0x2aaaabe06540>

sizes is 3000

sizeS is 3000

sizeS_tot is 3000
```

Comment: `data seems to be getting appended rather than just being added` what do you mean?

Comment: Could you give us an example of your output?

Comment: You are assigning over `S_tot` each loop iteration...

Comment: The array size keeps on increasing by 1000 which is the size of the array, I want to keep adding! I posted the output where the sizes are displayed after 3 iterations.

Comment: A note: you would probably benefit greatly from a Python debugger. Maybe check out PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! It was a scope issue. So I need to define the x[],s[] arrays inside the for loop while define the S_tot[], etc. outside it.

Here is the altered code:I am sorry I don't have a lot of comments in the code!

```
S_tot =[0]*1000
P_tot =[0]*1000
D_tot =[0]*1000
N=3
for i in xrange(1,N+1,1):
        x=[]
        s=[]
        p=[]
        d=[]
        stri = str(i)
        dos_file =open("DOS"+stri,"r")
        #dos_file =open("DOS1","r")
        print 'filename is %s' % dos_file
        for line_aa in dos_file.readlines():
                line_aa=line_aa.split()
                x.append(line_aa[0])
                s.append(line_aa[1])
                p.append(line_aa[2])
                d.append(line_aa[3])
        #dos_file.close()   
        x=[float(i) for i in x]
        s=[float(i) for i in s]
        p=[float(i) for i in p]
        d=[float(i) for i in d]
        #print 's0 is %f' % s[0]     
        #print 's1 is %f' % s[1]     
        #sizes=len(s)
        #print 'sizes is %d' % sizes
        #S_tot=[0]*sizes
        #print 'S0 is %f' % S[0]     
        #print 'S1 is %f' % S[1]     
        #sizeS=len(s)
        #print 'sizeS is %d' % sizeS
        #dos_file.close()   
        #S_tot=[a + b for a, b in zip(s, S_tot)]
        S_tot=[sum(terms) for terms in zip(s, S_tot)]
        P_tot=[sum(terms) for terms in zip(p, P_tot)]
        D_tot=[sum(terms) for terms in zip(d, D_tot)]
        print 'S_tot0 is %f' % S_tot[0]
        print 'S_tot1 is %f' % S_tot[1]
        print 'P_tot1 is %f' % P_tot[1]
        print 'D_tot1 is %f' % D_tot[1]
        dos_file.close()

print 'endS0 is %f' % S_tot[0]
print 'endS1 is %f' % S_tot[1]
print 'endP_tot1 is %f' % P_tot[1]
print 'endD_tot1 is %f' % D_tot[1]
~                                                                                                                                                                                       
~                                                                                                                                                                                       
~                                                                                                                                                                                       
~                                                                                                                                                                                       
~
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you want is this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [3, 4, 1, 2]
print([sum(items) for items in zip(a, b, c)])
```

results in

```
[6, 9, 8, 11]
```

Here, I'm using [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), and [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Hanging around Stack Overflow makes me appreciate the part of the Zen of Python which reads "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: Wow, within a minute of each other. It's true, `sum` and `zip` is the correct answer here.

Comment: I have the zip command with sum but it still is appending rather than just adding! Please have a look at my code and the output

Comment: @Aakash, the output doesn't appear to be up to date with your current code.

Comment: I am sorry, Yes thats basically working on three arrays of size 1000. These are read from files DOS1, DOS2 and DOS3

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. At the top you specified this is the operation you wanted. It may not currently be applied properly. It looks like you're using it for S_tot? However, you're immediately throwing the values out. Maybe you want `S_tot=[sum(items) for items in zip(s, S, S_tot)]`, but it's a little difficult to tell. It's generally a good idea to name your variables clearly and always avoid differentiating variable names by case.

Comment: @Kupiakos I dont understand why the size of these arrays becomes 2000 and 3000 (i.e. an increment of 1000). All I intend is to read each file DOS1, DOS2, etc. and then grab a column as you showed in the example, and keep on adding them until I am done with all of them. But the array size keeps changing. If I am adding 3 arrays of size 1000 in each iteration, I shouldn't get these sized to increase after each iteration. Sorry if i was not able to make myself clear earlier.

Comment: `s` is a list that you keep appending to with `s.append(line_aa[1])`. You never clear it, and you never do anything else with the data. Maybe you want to replace `s.append(line_aa[1])` with `s += float(line_aa[1])`? If you want to solve the problem yourself, I'd recommend rewriting this with better variable names and comments.

Answer (score 0):

zip is powerful:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=[2,3,4,5]
>>> c=[3,4,1,2]
>>> sums = [sum(terms) for terms in zip(a,b,c)]
>>> sums
[6, 9, 8, 11]
```